# How to filter Observable of array with rxjs 6 with async

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-services, rxjs5, rxjs6

I have an Observable which return as observable of data and that is binding with async using HTML.

here I have called the service.

```
this.ProductOptions = this.ProductService.fetchProduct();
```

In HTML we have binding as

```
Productoptions | async.
```

It's working fine.

In another function call, I have filtered based on product name, but it's not working.

```
getCategory() {
  const productListOptions = this.productOptions.pipe(
    switchMap((itemList: BindingModel[]) => itemList.filter(product => product.name !== "Active")));

  console.log(this.productListOptions);
}
```

`this.productOptions` shows below in console.

[image]

---

But when I subscribe to the observable.

```
this.productService.fetchproducts().subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

I am getting below format

```
[{id:1,name:"Active"},{id:1,name:"InActive"}]; i need to filter based on Active
```

Comment: can you console.log your `itemList` before applying `.filter` call on it, i just want to see what your itemList turns out and whether the filter is applied with the correct level of dot access @Mohamed Sahir

Comment: In console screenshot i have attached on above, when i do the subscribe i have get the values  [{id:1,name:"Active"},{id:1,name:"InActive"}]; how to see the observable values

Comment: If one of the answers did answer your question, could you mark it?

Answer (score 0):

Your using switchMap where you should use the map operator.

The differences:

**switchMap**

Convert an Observable that emits Observables into a single Observable that emits the items emitted by the most-recently-emitted of those Observables

In other words, the function defined inside the switchMap must return an observable. Your example returns an array of items, not an observable

**map**

Transform the items emitted by an Observable by applying a function to each item.